# How to change font face with siunitx while preserving alignment

Tags: tables, siunitx

Suppose I have some numbers which are nearly, but not quite equal. I wish to have these digits aligned, but also want to make the ones that differ bold so they stand out. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|S[detect-weight,table-format=2.15e+2]}
    Algorithm & {Residual} \\ \hline
    A & 14.082603491982\textbf{647}e-08 \\
    B & 14.082603491982\textbf{575}e-08 \\
    C & 1.616306278792575e-08 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which results in the following:
[image: misaligned example]

My question is: is it possible to have the nice typesetting of `siunitx` while also having boldface? I'm actually okay with anything that helps the last three digits stand out, whether that be underlining or something else.